# Magento extensions not loaded

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a brand new installation of Magento CE 1.7.0.2 on my local machine, and cannot get any extensions to load. They install properly in the Magento Connect Manager and appear in the list as installed, but there is no effect in the admin interface.

I have successfully installed Magento and these extensions before, so I'm not a complete noob. The extensions I'm trying to get working are these (both theoretically compatible with 1.7):

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization/magento-community-modules-french-france-language-pack.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/oscommerce-migration-tool.html

What *should* happen with these extensions is:

- The admin interface should be in French (remains in English despite switching back and forth to French / other languages)
- There should be a "oscommerce" menu item under System > Import/Export (not there)

What I've tried (many times and in every possible combination):

- Logging out and back in
- Flushing all caches
- Deleting all cookies, exiting the browser, restarting apache, restarting the machine
- Reinstalling/Uninstalling both extensions
- Reinstalling Magento with a clean database and clean filesystem

I've followed the installation instructions to a tee. Magento is in developer mode ("SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1" and "php_flag display_errors On" in .htaccess). There are no relevant errors in the logs and no PHP errors. The www user (under which runs the apache process) has full write permissions to the *entire* directory (also tried just /var, /app/etc and /)

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a chmod -R 777 on the root of your magento installation to test if the moduls start to work then.

Comment: Thanks Andre. Though I *swear* I did this several times before, I did it again for the sake of argument, reinstalled *again* my modules, and it worked. Is this seriously the way that we're expected to run a Magento site?? By making the entire directory writable to *everyone*?   This is without doubt the most terrible idea since Windows ME. The installation doc claims it needs only app/etc and var, which is clearly false. So exactly *WHICH* directories need to be writable?

Comment: Only var/cache and media/ need to be writable by apache everything else just readable. maybe 755 on those and 644 the rest?

Comment: excactly. use 777 only for testing.