# Extensions in magento are installed successfully but not visible in back end

Tags: magento-1.7

I have installed more than two extension in magento 1.7 and they are successfully installed but when proceed on next step they are not visible like one extension is tonbo color picker it's not visible in design tab and other one is module creator after installing it on local i got one more menu in System tab that is module creator but not on live please suggest what to do here to make them visible on live too.

this issue was related to permission,and now it's solved after doing  chmod -R 777 on the root of my magento installation folder.

i got this solution from [Magento extensions not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366344/magento-extensions-not-loaded)

thanks!

Comment: But giving 777 permissions on root folder is not the good idea. Try to give 777 permissions to app, var, cache, downloader folders only.

Comment: Can You check error log.it gives some information.